# Send midi with AKSequencer over virtual output

Tags: midi, audiokit

I’m trying to send a midi data from a .mid file with AKSequencer(), on a virtual output to use it outside the app (more detail below). **My problem is my AKSequencer doesn't send midi outside my app** like I would like to do with the virtualOuput port.

```
// My midiOutput is set like this: 
    let midiOut = AKMIDI()
    midiOut.createVirtualOutputPort()
    midiOut.openOutput() 

//And my AKSequencer connect to the midiOuput like this: 
     sequencer.setGlobalMIDIOutput(midiOut.virtualOutput)
```

- I set up an AKSampler() to be sure my AKSequencer work fine.
- I think my issue provide either from my connexion to the midiOutput, either my use of AKSequencer not design to send midi like I imagine.

To enter into details, I’m trying to send MIDI over Bluetooth from an iOS app to a DAW. Thank the CABTMIDILocalPeripheralViewController. it’s very easy to set up a connection to send midi when two devices are connected established. I achieve to send midi with AKMIDI().sendNoteOnMessage() so I’m sure the connection is not the problem.

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: AKSequencer doesn't send midi on the virtualOutput. Maybe I'm wrong with the virtualOutput. Is the right object to use to send midi outside the app?

Comment: AKSequencer could send MIDI to AKMIDICallbackInstrument or AKMIDIListener objects. You could reroute the MIDI from callback instrument or midi listener to other apps through virtualOutput. If you want to send midi to hardware or other outputs, like CoreMIDI Network Session, you need to enable that output like `midi.openOutput("Session 1")`. You can get the all destinations by `midi.destinationNames` and let the user pick which one they want to open. Than open that output with destination name that user pick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sending MIDI outside with `AKSequencer` a bit tricky. You need to either use `AKMIDICallbackInstrument` or your own `AKMIDIListener` to get MIDI from the sequencer and reroute outside of your app by `AKMIDI` output.

There is a discussion on this thread:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/audiokit/6VkayJMpMvY

Also, you may want to check out my MIDISequencer library built top on `AKSequencer` with iOS and Mac examples:
https://github.com/cemolcay/MIDISequencer